# Angular Material use the checked status of checkbox as a readonly basis of other control in form group

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new on angular and I wanted to use the checked status of the checkbox as basis on the readonly property of textarea.

```
<div fxlayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" *ngFor="let test of cosmetriTests.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
 <mat-form-field class="w-25-p" appearance="outline" >
      <textarea [id]="'actualCoaField_'+i"
          matInput
          formControlName="actual_coa_qualifier"
          (keyup) = "evaluateCoa()"
          [readonly] = "test.checked.include==false"
          required>
      </textarea>
 </mat-form-field>

 <mat-checkbox
     formControlname="include"
     [checked]="true"
     [required]="true"
 </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: You can do simply [readonly] = "!nameOfYourFormControl.controls.include.value", and forget using (change)

Comment: @Eliseo In my part, since I am using "let test of cosmetriTests.controls" will this be [readonly]="test.include.value" right? Is it correct to get the value property of check box instead of the checked property?

Comment: Sorry, I missed you're in a FormArray :(. test is a FormGroup, so must be test. **controls** .include.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an eventemmiter function on your checkbox value change,

My ts code:

```
readOnlyTextArea = true;
textAreaReadonly( value ) {
  this.readOnlyTextArea = !this.readOnlyTextArea;
}
```

My Html code:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <textarea [readonly] = "readOnlyTextArea" matInput placeholder="Leave a 
      comment"></textarea>

</mat-form-field>
<mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlname="include" [checked]="true" 
       (change)="textAreaReadonly($event)" [required]="true">Checkbox
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: pretty clever, never thought of this. This works for me man. since they're dynamic, I just put index on it and voila!!! as expected. Tnx for this

Comment: @Imrul, you can make it with no (change). If you want to refered to the value of a field of a ReactiveForm in the .html you can use ="nameOfForm.controls.nameOfField.value"

Answer (score 0):

Not having material handy, I just tried with straight angular, and got this working :

```
        <textarea [id]="'actualCoaField_'+i"
             matInput
             [disabled]="!myCheckbox.checked"
         >
         </textarea>

         <input type="checkbox"
             #myCheckbox
             (change)="true"
         />
```

Couple of things to note :

1) the #myCheckbox does NOT need to be appended with the loop index, since template names are local to their scope (and the *ngFor creates a new ng template on each iteration), and

2) The seemingly unnecessary `(change)=true` is in fact necessary, since it persuades Angular to perform screen update.

Comment: helpful in some ways but I want to stick on the angular material man.

Comment: @code4funN4money This solution is standard Angular, so I don't see any reason why it would behave any differently in material.  Try it, and let me know  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngModel for 2 way data binding .

```
 <mat-form-field class="w-25-p" appearance="outline" >
          <textarea [id]="actualCoaField"
              matInput
              (keyup) = "evaluateCoa()"
              [readonly] = "!isCheckboxChecked"
              required>
          </textarea>
     </mat-form-field>

    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isCheckboxChecked"
         (change)="checked()"
         [required]="true">
     </mat-checkbox>
```

Now based on checkbox status textarea will be enabled/disabled.

Created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8fuu3p?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.html

Comment: whoever is downvoting state the reason ,I have working code example here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to `[readonly] = "test.include.value==false"` and check if it works

```
<div fxlayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" *ngFor="let test of cosmetriTests.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
 <mat-form-field class="w-25-p" appearance="outline" >
      <textarea [id]="'actualCoaField_'+i"
          matInput
          formControlName="actual_coa_qualifier"
          (keyup) = "evaluateCoa()"
          [readonly] = "test.checked.include==false"
          required>
      </textarea>
 </mat-form-field>

 <mat-checkbox
     formControlname="include"
     [checked]="true"
     [required]="true"
 </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still do not work to me.